# jQuery validation: remote method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, email

I have a question regarding jquery validation plugin and specifically remote method.

Say I have a `checkEmail.php` script that is used to check the email address against the database. I also use the `required:true` and `email:true`. I want to add a spinner while getting the response from the server and hide it when its done.

At the same time i want to show a green tick icon next to the email field if the result from the server is `true`.

**I used the following code:**

```
$('#form').validate({

    rules:  {

        email:  {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: 'js/ajax/checkEmail.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    email: function() {
                        return $('#email').val();
                    }
                },
                beforeSend: function() {

                    //CODE TO SHOW THE SPINNER
                },
                success:function(output){

                    //CODE TO HIDE THE SPINNER


                    if(output == 'true')
                    {
                        //SHOW GREEN TICK

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //SHOWS THE CUSTOM ERROR FROM SERVER
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages:   {

        email:  {
            required: 'Please enter your email',
            email: 'Please enter a valid email address'
        }
    }
});
```

Say the following email address `foo@bar.com` is in the database. The remote method will then return `true`. At the same time both `required` and `email` methods are satisfied. So the green tick will be displayed.

## The problem:

If i dissatisfy one of the required, email methods, then the error message will automatically be displayed but the green tick will remain. I have tried to use `.valid()` after the `.validate()` to check when the form is not valid and then remove the green tick. Its not working.

```
if($('#form').valid())
{
   //REMOVE GREEN TICK : --> NOT WORKING
}
```

Is there anything I can do to manipulate the DOM if the form is not valid? In other words how can I make this work?

Thanks in advance,

Christos

Comment: Hide the tic in the else portion of the success function?

Comment: I dont think this will work, since the else part is in the remote method that is activated if the required and email methods are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

In the messages portion of your validator, do the same as you did with your data in the `remote`. Do a function or an anonymous function:

```
function resetCheck(message)
    {
        // Whatever code you want to use to remove check icon here
        $("#checkmark").remove();
        // Just return the message
        return message;
    }

// Messages part of your validation:
...
messages:   {
        email:  {
            required: resetCheck('Please enter your email'),
            email: resetCheck('Please enter a valid email address')
        }
    }
```